# Bash access overwritten shell commands

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

This is more for my edification than a problem I'm experiencing.  In my `.bashrc` I've overwritten `cd` with a function that runs `pushd` so I can easily pop the stack without thinking about it.

```sh
cd() {
    [[ -z $* ]] && cd ~ || pushd "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

Now suppose for some reason I want to access the original `cd` command.  Is that possible?

I do something similar with my `code.exe` (I'm running Git Bash on Windows), where I detect if I'm running within VSCode Insiders, and if so, I alias `code` to the Insiders exe.  I set an alias `_code` to the original code.exe path so I can access if if I want to.  Can I do something similar with native shell commands that aren't executables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `command cd` for instance

Comment: or `builtin cd`